# Protractor firefox console log errors not appearing

Tags: javascript, firefox, protractor

I'm trying to get a hold of error messages in protractor. This works fine in Chrome:

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
            console.log(browserLog);
            browserLog.forEach(function (log) {
                if (log.level.value === 1000) {
                    numOfErrors++;
                }
            });
        });
```

but in Firefox I don't get any `SEVERE (1000) messages` but many of lower level `800` and `900`, even though I can see the error messages in the browser.

I also tried to use the protractor plugin for console errors, but that for some reason is always passing, even when errors happen.

Comment: What firefox and protractor versions are you using?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? Please consider accepting @alecxe response

Answer (score 1):

According to the relevant [Console plugin does not fail on error on Firefox](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2058) issue, console plugin reliably works in *Chrome only*:

> This is because the firefoxdriver implements log grabbing slightly
>   differently. We should clarify that the console plugin is only
>   guaranteed against chrome.